# PHP: append rewrite rules?

Tags: php, .htaccess

In my mysql db i have a list of 300 products (some old or discontinued)
but I want to to redirect users from, say, all the discontinued products from 1-50 to a specific url.

```
example.com/product-a
example.com/product-b
example.com/product-c
etc..
```

redirect to

```
example.com/product-x
```

I'd like to avoid to do it manually. Is there a way i can append my rules to the .htaccess file?

Comment: You aren't providing enough information. Are they all sequential? and how? by alphabet or number or what?

Answer (score 0):

This rule should do it:

```
RewriteRule ^/?(product-a|product-b|product-c)(/.*)?$ /product-x [L,NC,R=301]
```

Add more products in regex alternation after `|`